# Additional validation logic before sending a request to the external system

Tags: validation, grails, groovy, instagram-api

I'm publishing a comment on Instagram using their API. In the documentation they describe the rules that the message that is being sent has to pass. So far my approach always was to add the validation layer just before the message would be sent to the service checking if it satisfies all the requirements. I preferred to get back to the user quicker with the proper error without sending any requests to the social network.

It requires to maintain additional logic in my application and in case of Instagram, where rules are not so simple (like e.g. just limiting the length of the message) I started thinking if that's the optimal approach.

For example, one of the requirements on comments is that they cannot contain more than 4 hashtags which forces me to keep some logic to be able to check how many hashtags are in a string.

Would you think that the effort put into keeping that validation is worth it? I always thought so, but am not so sure any more.

Comment: This question would probably be better suited for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com); keeping that in mind, you could have an ajax call to a grail's action that validates the object - you could use the same `validate()` method (and associated domain validators that come along with it) so no duplication of code.

Comment: The validation that I'm talking about has nothing to do with the domain model so I don't have any validator which I could use. The question is about the duplication of the validation that is performed by the social network and if I should have the copy of these rules in my application in case even these rules are getting complicated.

Answer (score 0):

> Would you think that the effort put into keeping that validation is
>   worth it? I always thought so, but am not so sure any more.

Absolutely yes unless you don't care about user at all.

User is your primary value and his comfort is above all things. So, double validation is a must for a good software.

I think you shouldn't struggle to implement absolutely ALL Instagram checks, but at least most of those, that users fail most often.